# Continuous variable Fourier gate and teleportation circuit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

I am studying the teleporting circuit of continuous variable showed by  [Weedbrook, pag. 37. Fig. (164)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234); in that, they propose an input state to the circuit as

$$ \left|\psi\right>\left|0\right>_{p_{2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \int\int dq_{1}dq_{2}~\psi(q_{1}) \left|q_{1}\right>\left|q_{2}\right>, \tag{1}$$

where $\left|\psi\right>=\int dq_{1}~\psi(q_{1}) \left|q_{1}\right>$ is an arbitrary state expanded over the position basis $q_{1}$, and $\left|0\right>_{p_{2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \int dq_{2}~ \left|q_{2}\right>$ is a highly squeezed state, approximating a vacuum eigenstate of momentum. According to the presented circuit a CPHASE gate $\hat{C}_{z}=e^{(i/2)\hat{q}_{1}\hat{q}_{2}}$  is applied to entagle the two modes, that is

$$ \hat{C}_{z}\left|\psi\right>\left|0\right>_{p_{2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \int \int dq_{1}dq_{2}~\psi(q_{1}) e^{(i/2)q_{1}q_{2}}\left|q_{1}\right>\left|q_{2}\right>,
 \tag{2}$$

now, a momentum proyective measurement is made on the first mode by applying the proyector $\left| m_{1}\right> \left< m_{1}\right|$ (where $m_{1}$ stands as a momentum variable), that is

$$\left|m_{1}\right> \left<m_{1}\right|\hat{C}_{z}\left|\psi\right>\left|0\right>_{p_{2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \int \int dq_{1}dq_{2}~\psi(q_{1}) e^{(i/2)q_{1}q_{2}} \left|m_{1}\right> \left\langle m_{1}\right.\left|q_{1}\right>\left|q_{2}\right>, \tag{3}$$

using $\left\langle m_{1}\left|q_{1}\right> \right. =\left(2\sqrt{\pi} \right)^{-1}e^{-iq_{1}m_{1}/2}$, the above equation can be written as

$$ \left|m_{1}\right> \left<m_{1}\right|\hat{C}_{z}\left|\psi\right>\left|0\right>_{p_{2}} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int \int dq_{1}dq_{2}~\psi(q_{1}) e^{(i/2)q_{1}\left(q_{2}-m_{1}\right)} \left|m_{1}\right> \left|q_{2}\right>, \tag{4}$$

according to [Weedbrook et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234) the corresponding state for the first mode becomes

$$\left|m_{1}\right> \left<m_{1}\right|\hat{C}_{z}\left|\psi\right>\left|0\right>_{p_{2}} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int \int dq_{1}dq_{2}~\psi(q_{1}) e^{(i/2)q_{1}\left(q_{2}-m_{1}\right)} \left|q_{2}\right>, \tag{5}$$

in order to show the teleportation of the continuous variable state $\left|\psi\right>$, the authors say that the above state can be written as

$$\left|\psi'\right>=\hat{X}(m_{1}) \hat{F} \left|\psi\right>, \tag{6}$$

where $\hat{X}(m_{1})=\exp \left(-im_{1}\hat{p}/2 \right)$ is the displacement gate which gives a shift by an amount $m_{s}$ in $q$ direction ([see: Weedbrook, lines after Eq. (148)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234)) according to $\hat{X}(m_{1})\left|q\right>=\left|q + m_{1}\right>$; besides, the gate acts on the position basis as $\hat{X}(m_{1})\left|p\right>=e^{-im_{s}p}\left|p\right>$. On the other hand, the Fourier gate acts on the quadrature eigenstates according to ([see: Weedbrook, Eq. (154, 155)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234))

$$\hat{F}\left|q\right>=\left|p\right>, \tag{7}$$
$$\hat{F}\left|p\right>=\left|-q\right>, \tag{8}$$
$$\hat{F}^{\dagger}\left|q\right>=\left|-p\right>, \tag{9}$$
$$\hat{F}^{\dagger}\left|p\right>=\left|q\right>, \tag{10}$$

and the position and momentum basis

$$\left|q\right>=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int dp~e^{-iqp/2} \left|p\right>, \tag{11} $$
$$\left|p\right>=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int dq~e^{iqp/2} \left|q\right>. \tag{12} $$

Concretely, **I want to show that Eq. (6) above is equivalent to the state given by Eq. (5)**; then,  I first do the following procedure:

I apply the Fourier gate to the state $\left|\psi\right>$ expanded in the position basis

$$\hat{F}\left|\psi\right>=\int dq_{1}~\psi(q_{1}) \hat{F}\left|q_{1}\right> \\
= \int dq_{1}~\psi(q_{1}) \left|p_{1}\right>\\
=\int dq_{1}~\left\langle q_{1}\right. \left|\psi\right> \left|p_{1}\right> \\
=\int dq_{1}~\left\langle q_{1}\right|\left( \int dp'~ \left|p'\right>\left<p'\right| \right)\left|\psi\right> \left|p_{1}\right> \\
=\int\int dq_{1} dp'~\left\langle q_{1}\right.\left|p'\right>\left\langle p'\right. \left|\psi\right> \left|p_{1}\right>\\
= \left(2\sqrt{\pi} \right)^{-1}\int\int dq_{1} dp'~\psi\left( p'\right)  e^{iq_{1}p'/2}\left|p_{1}\right>,\tag{13}$$

where in the first line I use Eq. (7); in the fourth line I introduce a completeness relation for the momentum states $\left|p'\right>$, and in the last line I use $\left\langle q_{1}\right.\left|p'\right>=\left(2\sqrt{\pi} \right)^{-1}e^{i q_{1} p'/2}$,

after, I apply the displacement gate $\hat{X}(p')$ to the state in the last line above

$$\hat{X}(p')\hat{F}\left|\psi\right>=\left(2\sqrt{\pi} \right)^{-1}\int\int dq_{1} dp'~\psi\left( p'\right)  e^{iq_{1}p'/2}\hat{X}(p')\left|p_{1}\right>\\
=\left(2\sqrt{\pi} \right)^{-1}\int\int dq_{1} dp'~\psi\left( p'\right)  e^{iq_{1}p'/2}e^{-ip'p_{1}}\left|p_{1}\right>\\
=\left(2\sqrt{\pi} \right)^{-1}\int\int dq_{1} dp'~\psi\left( p'\right)  e^{ip'\left(q' - p_{1} \right)/2}\left|p_{1}\right>. \tag{14}$$

However, the last state is not equivalent to that given by Eq. (5). **Therefore, some hint to obtain the state Eq. (5) from the state Eq. (6)**?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow all the steps and I did not consult the paper. However, I may have some helpful hints.

Firstly, in (2) I would suggest "pushing" the exponentiated operator "through" the two gets to turn it into an ordinary exponential:
$$ \exp(\tfrac{i}{2}\hat{q}_1\hat{q}_2)|q_1\rangle|q_2\rangle 
=|q_1\rangle|q_2\rangle \exp(\tfrac{i}{2}{q}_1{q}_2) . $$
Otherwise there would be a problem in (3) since (if I understand correctly) the $\langle m_1|$ cannot be passed through the exponentiated operator. With the exponentiated operator given as an ordinary exponential, one can overlap $\langle m_1|q_1\rangle$ to get the exponential factor, but not as an operator. The resulting combine exponential factor now serves as a shifted Fourier kernel, with which you can Fourier transform $\psi(q_1)$. That then effectively gives you the expression in (6).

Hope it helps.